# Sublime regex comma replace character

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, sublimetext2

I have a approx 22000 data items in the file which has data given as below

```
a0001, = , [,23.3,88.9,]
b0001, = , [, 21.3,98.2,]
b2312, = , [, 11.3,55.1,]
```

I am using Sublime and trying to remove / clean data so that it can be used in a ruby application 
I am trying to remove few commas using sublime find / replace option
Even after trying various regex option couldn't get anything to give me data in the following form

```
a0001 =  [23.3,88.9]
b0001 =  [21.3,98.2]
b2312 =  [11.3,55.1]
```

in the form of arrays

Help needed please...

Comment: Non re replace `, = , [,` with `=[` then `,]` with `]` then `  ` with `<empty>` then `=` with ` =  `

Comment: Instead of a regular expression, why not just highlight `, = ,` and select all duplicates (CTRL+D or ⌘D) then edit them all simultaneously? Likewise, rectangular selections can often make fixing this super easy.

Comment: Why don't you just parse it as is in Ruby? Why do you feel like you have to "clean" something for Ruby, when Ruby is better equipped to parse it in the first place?

Comment: @MarkThomas For one, that's not valid Ruby, so there's that. If this is something intended to be used in code, it makes sense to transform it into an idealized form before rolling it in rather than having some crappy, badly formatted metadatafile in a format that makes no sense. Imagine updating this in the future and having to produce a new file with the original, corrupted format.

Comment: @tadman, it doesn't need to be valid Ruby to parse it. I would *hope* the intent is not to `eval` it, as there would be better approaches.

Comment: Automatically generating code is not necessarily a bad thing. I'd recommend using JSON, YAML, or even CSV for storing data like this, but if the goal is to wrangle it into a format where it could be loaded with `require` then it'll need cleaning up.

Comment: Alex K solution is very simple and very easy to use. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pure regular expression version:

```
^(\w+),\s*=\s*,\s*\[,\s*(\d+\.\d+),\s*(\d+\.\d+),\]
```

Replace with:

```
$1 = [ $2, $3 ]
```

The goal here is to capture the data using `(...)` and then later position and format it as precisely as you want. Using `\s*` makes your expression a lot more lenient regarding space that may or may not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below regex

Find what: `[,]|(\d,\d+)`
Replace with: `$1`